# Windows 7 on SSD - power supply

Tags: windows, power-supply

Im trying to do a clean install of windows 7 on an old desktop.   What Im noticing is that sometimes the SSD is recognized by the BIOS (ie. shows proper make and model etc) and sometimes isnt just shows windings for name / ID.

I believe this is why im getting the "no drives were found" during installation, ie. it does not see the disk (also DISKPART says there are no disks as well). The SSD is fine, it works and when I plug it into a USB enclosure, the installer sees it, but does not allow me to install since its over USB.

I am also getting an Overclock/Overvoltage error on the BIOS post occasionally.

I am wondering if this is all pointing to a bad Power Supply?? (the SATA port still works with my old drive).

Comment: im also thinking the ssd may not be supported by this old board (asus p5l-vm 1394)